# CGI application with SQL LINQ error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, cgi

I have a problem running a C# CGI app on windows home premium ISS server.
My code is as follows:

```
        Console.Write("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
        string conn = "Data Source=|C:\\DB|\\RegisteredUsers.sdf";
        Console.WriteLine(conn); // Added for debugging
        RegisteredUsers userdb = new RegisteredUsers(conn); //DBML file from SqlMetal Here
```

The error i get is:

```
Data Source=RegisteredUsers.sdf

Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration     system failed to initialize ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess    access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates,    Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access,  String path)
at System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String dir, Boolean normalize)
at System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.Initialize()
    at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses()
    at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetProvider(String providerName)
    at     Syst em.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize(IData   Services dataServices, Object connection)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection, M appingSource mapping)
    at Validate.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It seems the error is either in string `conn = @"Data Source=RegisteredUsers.sdf";` or
`RegisteredUsers userdb = new RegisteredUsers(conn);` and i have no reason to believe that the string definition is bad so i think it is in
`RegisteredUsers userdb = new RegisteredUsers(conn);`

Answer (score 0):

Connection string should not be a verbatim string literal; just remove the @ sign and escape any back slash with a back slash.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same error.
The line is now:
string conn = "Data Source=RegisteredUsers.sdf";

Did i mention this works fine if i just start the EXE from cmd?

Comment: Hello, no you didnt mention, but did you tried this as well? string conn = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\RegisteredUsers.sdf";